# Recordset BOF/EOF cannot handle Nulls

Tags: ms-access, vba, recordset

I have a form and want to display a message when there are no records. The SQL in the following code displays no records (Null) (as it should at present). The function does not work as I wish. It neither returns a number nor displays the message. If I put the function in a form that does have records, it counts them accurately.

```vb
Public Function NumRecs() As Integer

Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT tblClient.ClientName, tblInvoices.SentToPayer, [Adjustment]+[MyFee]+[DBSFee] AS TotFees, tblClient.ClientID, tblDisclosure.ApplicantForenames, tblDisclosure.AppEmail " & _
                             "FROM ((tblInvoiceDetails INNER JOIN tblDisclosure ON tblInvoiceDetails.DiscLookup = tblDisclosure.ID) INNER JOIN tblInvoices ON tblInvoiceDetails.InvoiceLookup = tblInvoices.ID) INNER JOIN ((tblOfficerDetails INNER JOIN tblOfficers ON tblOfficerDetails.OfficerLookup = tblOfficers.ID) INNER JOIN tblClient ON tblOfficerDetails.ClientLookup = tblClient.ClientID) ON tblInvoices.AppLookup = tblClient.ClientID " & _
                             "WHERE (((tblInvoices.DatePaid) Is Null)) ")

If Not rs.BOF And Not rs.EOF Then
    NumRecs = Me.Recordset.RecordCount
Else
    DisplayMessage ("No records.")
    NumRecs = 0
End If

rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing

End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *"I have a form and want to display a message when there are no records."*

You can accomplish that task without opening another `DAO.Recordset`.  Just use `RecordsetClone`, which already exists.

```vb
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim lngRowCount As Long

    lngRowCount = 0
    With Me.RecordsetClone
        If Not (.BOF And .EOF) Then
            .MoveLast
            lngRowCount = .RecordCount
        End If
    End With
    MsgBox lngRowCount & " records"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the recordcount with DAO, you need to MoveLast. Also, try changing the 'EOF' check (see below):

```
Public Function NumRecs() As Integer
Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim strSQL as String

strSQL = "SELECT tblClient.ClientName, tblInvoices.SentToPayer, [Adjustment]+[MyFee]+[DBSFee] AS TotFees, tblClient.ClientID, tblDisclosure.ApplicantForenames, tblDisclosure.AppEmail " & _ 
"FROM ((tblInvoiceDetails INNER JOIN tblDisclosure ON tblInvoiceDetails.DiscLookup = tblDisclosure.ID) INNER JOIN tblInvoices ON tblInvoiceDetails.InvoiceLookup = tblInvoices.ID) INNER JOIN ((tblOfficerDetails INNER JOIN tblOfficers ON tblOfficerDetails.OfficerLookup = tblOfficers.ID) INNER JOIN tblClient ON tblOfficerDetails.ClientLookup = tblClient.ClientID) ON tblInvoices.AppLookup = tblClient.ClientID " & _ 
"WHERE (((tblInvoices.DatePaid) Is Null))"

Set dbs = CurrentDB
Set rs = dbs.OpenRecordset(strSQL)

If Not rs.EOF Then 
    rs.MoveLast         ' ADD THIS LINE
    NumRecs = rs.RecordCount 
Else 
    DisplayMessage ("No records.") 
    NumRecs = 0 
End If

rs.Close 
Set rs = Nothing
dbs.Close
Set dbs = Nothing

End Function`
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried MoveLast previously. Nevertheless I have tried the whole of your code and I still get the same (wrong) result.

Comment: "Wrong" as in how? If there are NO records returned, do you get the display "No Records"? If any records are returned, you do not have a display specified. Do you have 'Option Explicit' and have compiled?

Comment: The same as in my original question: It neither returns a number nor displays the message. I have Option explicit and have compiled. in a short while I'll try a decompile of the whole frontend.

Comment: Yikes! Although I forgot to change your 'Set Rs = ...' to be 'Set Rs = dbs.Open..." You need to change your line 'Me.Recordset.RecordCount' to 'rs.RecordCount'

Comment: Thanks. Done that but still no progress, Same as before.

Comment: I assume you have a function named 'DisplayMessage'? Next, I would add a 'Debug.Print strSQL' and a breakpoint just before the 'Set dbs', than paste that SQL into the Query Designer and execute it just to see which path is true (records or no records). I would be tempted to add code to display a field from the RS - regardless of the EOF status to see if you get a field or an error.

Comment: Many thanks. I'll do this tomorrow. Yes I have a function 'DisplayMessage.

Comment: So your posted code loads up a recordset "rs", but you check the record count on the forms recordset? How on earth is there ANY kind of relation between a recordset you create called "rs", but in your code you check me.RecordSet.RecordCount?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I need a record count in DAO I always MoveLast and then MoveFirst however

```
Dim db as DAO.Database
Dim rst as DAO.Recordset
Dim strSQL as string

strSQL = ""  ' your query here

Set db=CurrentDB()
   Set rst=db.OpenRecordset(stSQL,dbOpenDynaSet)
      With rst
         If NOT (.EOF and .BOF) Then   ' There are records to be had
            Dim iRecCount as Integer
            .MoveLast: .MoveFirst       
              ' DAO typically requires the all records before the count
              ' count is correct
            iRecCount = .RecordCount

         Else    ' There are NOT records to be had
            ' ADD YOUR MESSAGE HERE FOR NO RECORDS.
         End If
         .Close
      End with
   Set rst=nothing
Set db=nothing
```

Optionally I build up my Queries external to VBA and add parameters. This why I know my query is producing the results I expect. Then you can reference your query as an object of QueryDefs of CurrentDB() object.  Then address you parameters as a property of QueryDef.

The following is a great read from Allen Browne on Recordsets.
http://allenbrowne.com/ser-29.html

Answer (score 0):

All you really need is:

```
Public Function NumRecs() As Integer

    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

    Set rs = Me.RecordsetClone
    If rs.RecordCount = 0 Then
        DisplayMessage ("No records.")
    Else
       rs.MoveLast
       NumRecs = rs.RecordCount
    End If
    rs.Close    
    Set rs = Nothing

End Function
```